# Searching for a String in a Hashtable - Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble searching a Hashtable for a particular String xmlMatch. This is derived from the contents of a particular div tag

I have included the code I use to search the XML and to define the String xmlMatch. I believe this is right and have shown so by printing it to the screen. I know this should be simple. I have created a quick test Hashtable and the same thing works there.

My TEST CODE - Works

```
String xmlMatch2 = "Two";
Hashtable<String, String> table2 = new Hashtable <String, String>();
table2.put("One", "Uno");
table2.put("Two", "Dos");
table2.put("Three", "Tres");

System.out.println(table2.containsKey(xmlMatch2));
String n = table2.get("Two");
System.out.println(n);
```

Works as expected, Prints the following to the console in Eclipse

true

DOS

My PRODUCTION CODE - Not Working

```
if(startPosition >1)            
{
    out.println("startPosition is greater or equal to 1 ");

    int subStringIndex = startPosition + startTag.length();
    subStringIndex = subStringIndex + 2; // +2 is necessary to remove "> after sliceXML             
    out.println(subStringIndex); 

    int endPosition = testContent.indexOf(endTag, subStringIndex);
    out.println(endPosition); 

    if(endPosition >= startPosition)
    {

    xmlMatch = testContent.substring(subStringIndex, endPosition);
    //out.println("This is my xmlMatch " + xmlMatch); //prints Florida
    }
```

The above print statement (when activated) confirms that xmlMatch is Florida

I then implement a simple Hashtable

```
Hashtable<String, String> table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    table.put("Florida","/PathToFile.txt");
    table.put("Telescope","/PathToFile2.txt");
    table.put("Galaxy","/PathToFile3.txt");
```

This is where my problems start!

```
out.println(table.containsKey(xmlMatch));
```

The above print statement prints false to the screen - I believe it should print true as xmlMatch which equals Florida is in the Hashtable.

```
String n = table.get(xmlMatch);
out.println(n);
```

And this prints null - I believe this should print /PathToFile.txt

However if I simply do this

```
out.println(xmlMatch);
```

It once again prints Florida to the screen

What am I doing wrong? I simply want to be able to search my Hashtable for a particular String. Any help is as always, much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Is it possible that I am having an issue with capital letters, or maybe my xmlMatch is passing an additional space character? e.g. "Florida "

**EDIT 2**
My xml div tag simply reads

```
<sliceXML>Florida</sliceXML>
```

**WORK AROUND SOLUTION**
Im adding this here as it is a solution to the problem but not to the question i asked.

with the help of [Joe K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854793/joe-k) i checked my endTag and found that i was nto able to encode the forward slash properly. I posted my work around answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285142/encoding-special-html-characters-in-java)

Comment: Have you checked that: `System.out.println("Florida".equals(xmlMatch))` prints true? There could be an extra space for example.

Comment: You mentioned that the contents are from a div tag. So can you please point out the result of out.println(xmlMatch.length()). I suspect you might have some lurking spaces in the string. You should try matching with xmlMatch.trim() which removes the spaces before and after the string.

Comment: @ assylias I just checked that now - it prints false - However when I try out.println(xmlMatch); Florida is printed to the page. As suggested by Joao Silva below I have tried to trim xmlMatch but it still prints null to the screen. Might this be a combination of problems?

Comment: @Suresh Kola out.println(xmlMatch.length()); prints 9 to the screen. looks like this is the issue. If i am right this should be printing 6 as java strings start at 0?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have whitespaces in your `xmlMatch`, use `trim()` to remove them:

```
String n = table.get(xmlMatch.trim());
out.println(n);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference, its a nice trick to know for the future, cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for white spaces??? Just trim the xmlMatch and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with "Florida".intern() ?

Comment: how will this help? hashmaps, use the `equals()` method internally.

Comment: @ColinD I have to agree with you. However, some of the subminor versions of JDK have String pool leaks(I faced it sometime back and took lot of time for me to figure it out). I wanted to see if it is the problem with JDK version before looking inspecting the code

Comment: I just tried out.println("florida.intern()); it prints florida to the screen. Note it prints florida with a lower case f, as it should do I believe?

Answer (score 0):

Java strings start with index 0, just like C arrays. Also, some XML serializers / deserializers tend to smallcaps the tags. So, a XML file such as:

```
 <Firefox>xxxx</Firefox>
```

will magically becomes:

```
 <firefox>xxxxx</firefox>
```

AFAIK, tags in a XML file are case-sensitive. Anyway, check for lower and upper caps if possible.

Oh, and yes: extra spaces in the tags could be a burden. Be careful with everything.

My last advice: since you're using Java, you could give SAX a go.