# Encoding special HTML characters < > / " in Java

Tags: java, html

I am using Java 1.6.0

I am looking for the correct methods of encoding special HTML characters in Java

My HTML

> ```
>  <div id="sliceXML">Florida</div>
> ```

I am trying to define a String xmlMatch as the content (in this case Florida) of the above div tag by using the below Java. However i believe i do not have my startTag or endTag defined correctly.

My Java

```
String testContent = contentPara;
String startTag = "\"sliceXML\">";                      
String endTag = "</div";                                        
String xmlMatch = null; 

int startPosition = testContent.indexOf(startTag);  

if(startPosition >1){

    int subStringIndex = startPosition + startTag.length();                                 
    int endPosition = testContent.indexOf(endTag, subStringIndex);              

    if(endPosition >= startPosition){
        xmlMatch = testContent.substring(subStringIndex, endPosition);
        out.println(xmlMatch.length()); 

    //out.println(startTag);

    out.println("Florida".equals(xmlMatch));
    out.println("florida".equals(xmlMatch));
}   
 }
```

Any help is much appricated. This would also allow me to answer a previous related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268002/searching-for-a-string-in-a-hashtable-java)

**EDIT**

**WORK AROUND SOLUTION**

As i explain below, i believe my issue was with the forward slash in `String endTag = "</div";` To get past this problem i simply changed my end tag to `String endTag = "<";`

I still dont know why this happened, it would be great if someone could answer.

Comment: no need to invent the wheel again, use an html parser

Comment: Your code works for me - why do you think it's not working? Make sure your input string is what you expect.

Comment: @Joe K Tanks for the tip, I tried to print out the endTag and discovered a problem. It appears to eb something with Java not recognising the forward slash "/" in the div tag "</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really use an HTML parser, such as the confusingly-named [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) (it's an HTML pretty-printer, but also gives you a DOM interface to the HTML structure).

It'll save you from headaches such as the parsing and handling character entities and encoding.

Comment: im not able to integrate a HTML Parser on this project as i am using old code which i am not in control of. I will keep it in mind for the future. I tried using `String startTag = "sliceXML&quot;&gt;"; // = sliceXML">` But it does not appear to be working.